# Xcode 4.5 and C++11 headers not found

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

For example, if I include 'chrono' or 'type_traits' it fails to find header and gives me an error, but if I use lamdas or auto/decltype it compiles fine. I am using Xcode 4.5.1  with the flags,  C++ Language Dialect=C++11[-std=c++11] and C++ Standard Library = libc++[LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support]

Any help on why the newer header file isn't being found?

Comment: Is it a file with .c extension? You can check compiler command in the build log to verify if Xcode is correctly adding -x c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to update xcode. Xcode wasn't fully updated yet.